# Use Modal in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I am making an android app with ReactNative. When a button is clicked, an alert shows up with the result (My code is ***Alert.alert(''Results:", returnResults(a,b,c))***. Is there a way I can use Modal and the function ***returnResults(a,b,c)*** with it to show the message in a more customised way?

The problem is that when I use normal alert, the text is different on every device and I want to prevent that.(I want to specify the font, its size etc)

Comment: ReacNative has a Modal component that works out of the box (https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal). 
If you need a few added animations, style customization, etc you can also use react-native-modal (https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal)

Answer (score 0):

```
const Modal = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Open Modal" onPress={() => setModal(true)} />
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={modal}
        onRequestClose={() => setModal(false)}
      >
        <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
          <View>
            <Text>This is the modal content</Text>
            <Button title="Close" onPress={() => setModal(false)} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found what i had been looking for. I just had to write the following code:

---

{returnResults(a,b,c)}